# How to show an image in a tool-tip on hovering over another image using CSS only?

Tags: html, image, css, tooltip

I've a set of three horizontal images. Now I've to show the tool-tip image for each of these images when user hovers his/her mouse cursor on any othe three images.

The issue is in every tool-tip I want to show an image. I've to achieve this thing through CSS only. No more jQuery and other stuff.

Can someone please help me in this regard please?

Following is the HTML of the set of three horizontal images.

```
<table style="width:100%" id="thumbs">
                      <tr>
                        <td><span style="cursor:pointer" ><img id="img1" width="80" height="80" src="http://78.134.51.289/theme/frontend/foxplus/style/default/image/layout/OpenIcon.png"/></span></td> 
                        <td><span style="cursor:pointer" ><img id="img2" width="80" height="80" src="http://78.134.51.289/theme/frontend/foxplus/style/default/image/layout/ColsedIcon.png"/></span> </td>
                        <td><span style="cursor:pointer" ><img id="img3" width="80" height="80" src="http://78.134.51.289/theme/frontend/foxplus/style/default/image/layout/SecretIcon.png"/></span> </td>
                      </tr>
                    </table>
```

Thanks in advance. You can take any images as tool-tip that are in `.png` format and having dimensions `273px * 224 px`

Comment: http://www.menucool.com/tooltip/css-tooltip

Comment: Something like this? [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/891tvx7d/)

Comment: Not going to dupe my answer, but i think the first snippet [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/27986354/3436942) could be altered for your needs. (where the cat 1-cat 4 are changed to images instead)

Comment: @Mr_Green:Yes exactly you got my issue. But I want to show three different tool-tip images for three different images. In your fiddle the same image is displaying as a tool-tip for every image. Can you please modify your fiddle accordingly? And thank you so much for showing interest in my issue and helping me too.

Comment: @user2839497 you just need to override as shown in this [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/891tvx7d/13/).

Answer (score 1):

```css
.ImgWithTool {
  position: relative;
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
}
.tool {
  display: none;
  width: 100%;
  height: 50px;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  text-align: center;
  background: #ddd;
}
.ImgWithTool:hover .tool {
  display: block;
}
.image-icon {
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  background: #ccc;
  display: inline-block;
}
.image-icon:hover {
  background: #eee;
}
```

```html
<td>
  <div class="ImgWithTool">
    <img id="img1" width="200px" height="200px" alt="your img" src="" />
    <div class="tool">
      <div class="image-icon">tool1</div>
      <div class="image-icon">tool2</div>
    </div>
  </div>
</td>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve that using `:after` or `:before` pseudo class elements.

```
tr span {
    display: block;
    position: relative;
}
tr span:hover {
    z-index: 1;
}
tr td span:hover:after {
    content:"";
    background-image: url('http://lorempixel.com/273/274/animals');
    position: absolute;
    top:50%;
    left: 50%;
    width: 273px;
    height: 274px;
}
tr td + td span:hover:after {
    background-image: url('http://lorempixel.com/273/274/sports');
}
tr td + td + td span:hover:after {
    background-image: url('http://lorempixel.com/273/274/people');
}
```

**[Working Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/891tvx7d/13/)**

Comment: Thank you so much for your immense help. Now just one kind request. If you observed closely that the tool-tip image for the left most image is not getting displayed completely. It is moving inside the right edge of screen. So I want to show every tool-tip image just below the image positioned at center so that all the tool-tip images will be displayed at center of the screen on hovering respective image. Also all the tool-tip images portion will be displayed completely. Also change the height of tool-tip images from 274 to 224. It would be great if you could make this change to your fiddle.

Comment: @user2839497 you just need to play with `top` and `left` css properties. Here is the [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/891tvx7d/14/).. please do those small changes..

Comment: :Thanks. But still I'm seeing the three tool-tip images at three different locations. I want to show the respective tool-tip images on hover just below the second image from the row of three horizontal images. In the new fiddle you provided this is not happening and I tried to play with left and right values but same is the result I'm getting. Could you please make this change to the fiddle you created? Thanks once again for the efforts you are taking.

Answer (score 0):

Are you trying to display a tooltip, or are you using this as an image gallery? Either way;

Tooltip:

```css
.image {
  display: inline-block;
  height: 150px;
  width: 200px;
  background: gray;
  position: relative;
  overflow:hidden;

}
.image img {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
}
.image .tooltip {
  position: absolute;
  transform: translate(100%);
  bottom: 0;
  width: 100%;
  color: white;
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
  transition: all 0.8s;
  opacity:0;
}
.image:hover .tooltip {
  position: absolute;
  transform: translate(0);
  opacity:1;
}
.tooltip:hover ~ .this{
  width:300px;
  }
```

```html
<div class="image">
  <img src="http://placekitten.com/g/300/300" />
  <div class="tooltip">
    i'm a tool tip.
  </div>
</div>
```

Gallery:

```css
#gallery {
  width: 300px;
  border: 3px solid red;
  text-align: center;
  padding-top: 300px;
  background: url(http://placekitten.com/g/300/300) no-repeat;
  position: relative;
}
#gallery li {
  display: inline;
}
#gallery span img {
  padding: 0 1em;
  transition:all 0.8s;
}
#gallery img {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  height: 300px;
  width: 300px;
}
#gallery span:hover {
  background: red;
}
#gallery span:hover ~ img {
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<ul id="gallery">
  <li>
    <span>Cat 1</span>
    <img src="http://placekitten.com/g/200/200" />
  </li>
  <li>
    <span>Cat 2</span>
    <img src="http://placekitten.com/g/300/200" />
  </li>
  <li>
    <span>Cat 3</span>
    <img src="http://placekitten.com/g/110/100" />
  </li>
  <li>
    <span>Cat 4</span>
    <img src="http://placekitten.com/g/140/100" />
  </li>
</ul>
```