# How to show different tool-tip images on hover in following scenario where the same tool-tip image is appearing?

Tags: html, image, css, tooltip

I've following HTML code :

```
<table style="width:100%" id="thumbs">
                      <tr>
                        <td><span style="cursor:pointer" ><img id="img1" width="80" height="80" src="http://78.674.67.234/theme/frontend/foxplus/style/default/image/layout/OpenIcon.png"/></span></td> 
                        <td><span style="cursor:pointer" ><img id="img2" width="80" height="80" src="http://78.674.67.234/theme/frontend/foxplus/style/default/image/layout/ColsedIcon.png"/></span> </td>
                        <td><span style="cursor:pointer" ><img id="img3" width="80" height="80" src="http://78.674.67.234/theme/frontend/foxplus/style/default/image/layout/SecretIcon.png"/></span> </td>
                      </tr>
                    </table>
```

Now I want to show the different tool tip image for each of the images on hovering over them. For it I've written following CSS but with it I'm able to show only one image in a tool-tip for all the three images which I want to avoid.

How should I achieve this?

Following is CSS code :

CSS Code :

```
    tr span {
    display: block;
    position: relative;
}
tr span:hover {
    z-index: 1;
}
tr span:hover:after {
    content:"";
    background-image: url('http://lorempixel.com/273/274/');
    position: absolute;
    top:50%;
    left: 50%;
    width: 273px;
    height: 274px;
}
```

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/891tvx7d/1/)

Comment: Same question as in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28024758/how-to-show-an-image-in-a-tool-tip-on-hovering-over-another-image-using-css-only, isn't it?

Answer (score 0):

I would make the following changes:

```
<style>
tr div {
    display: block;
    position: relative;
}
tr div:hover {
    z-index: 1;
}
tr div:hover .bigger_image {
    display: block;
}
.bigger_image {
    display: none;
    position: absolute;
    top:50%;
    left: 50%;
    width: 273px;
    height: 274px;
}
.img1 {
    background-image: url('');
}
.img2 {
    background-image: url('');
}
.img3 {
    background-image: url('');
}
</style>
```

And on the HTML:

```
<table style="width:100%" id="thumbs">
<tr>
    <td>
        <div style="cursor:pointer"><img class="img1" width="80" height="80" src=""/>
            <div class="img1 bigger_image"></div>
        </div>
    </td>
    <td>
        <div style="cursor:pointer"><img class="img2" width="80" height="80" src=""/>
            <div class="img2 bigger_image"></div>
        </div> 
    </td>
    <td>
        <div style="cursor:pointer"><img class="img3" width="80" height="80" src=""/>
            <div class="img3 bigger_image"></div>
        </div> 
    </td>
</tr>
</table>
```

And if you want the images in thumbs to be different just change or remove the class names on thumbs div.